# Pig UDF java out of index

Tags: java, apache-pig

I have got an access problem at pig with my UDF. I have done a grouping "Group BY" at received an output which is (Andi, 19495) and is described by pig as 
`C: {group: chararray, long}`.
Now I would like to format the output to (Andi 19495) as a string. But my UDF reports the following

> "Caught error from UDF: pigUDF.Output, Out of bounds access [Index: 1, Size: 1]"

I do not understand why this is happening.

Here is my java UDF:

```
package pigUDF;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.BagFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema.FieldSchema;

public class Output extends EvalFunc<Tuple>{
   TupleFactory tupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
   BagFactory mBagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();

   private static Tuple nullValue=TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(2);

   @Override
   public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

     if (input==null) return nullValue;

     Tuple t= tupleFactory.newTuple(1);

     String o = (String) input.get(0);
     int o1 = (Integer) input.get(1);


     String myString=o+" "+String.valueOf(o1);
     System.out.println(myString);

     t.set(0,myString);

     return t;        
   }

   @Override
   public Schema outputSchema(Schema input){

     Schema tupleSchema = new Schema();
     tupleSchema.add(new FieldSchema("group", DataType.CHARARRAY));        
     Schema s = new Schema (new FieldSchema(null, tupleSchema));
     return s;        
   }    
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Pig Script?You could probably use CONCAT to format your output instead of an UDF

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing an UDF you could use [CONCAT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#concat) and achieve the same result.

CONCAT the group with the resulting expression of ' ' and SUM(A).Also since CONCAT expects expressions of the same type,you will have to cast the int SUM(A) value to chararray.
Try changing

```
C = FOREACH A GENERATE group, SUM(A);
```

To

```
C = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(group,CONCAT(' ',(chararray)SUM(A)));
```

Comment: Very. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an alternate approach to get a similar result without invoking a custom UDF.

**INPUT**

*Andi,19495*

**SCRIPT**

A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,value:long);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(name,CONCAT(' ',(chararray)value));

DUMP B;

**OUTPUT**

*(Andi 19495)*

Hope this helps for now. I will post a UDF based solution too for you later.

Comment: Hi, I did the following command: C =FOREACH A GENERATE group, SUM(A);  The output is thence  (Andi, 19495) with C: {group: chararray, long}.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the solution below solved it